# Retrieve images from Mssql server database stored in Binary form

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core-mvc

I have stored a jpeg file in MSSql Database in binary format, Nnow I am unable to retrieve the original image file/jpeg file. Can anybody please help me?
I have used ASP.net core MVC  to store data in database.

ASP.net Core 2.2
MSSQL 2008
Visual studio 2019

```
     [HttpGet]
      public IActionResult Index1()
     {
        var ab = _context.Movie.Select(a => a.File).Single();

        return View(ab);
     }
```

---

```
    // POST: api/Uploads
    [HttpPost]
       public IActionResult Post(Movie entity, IFormFile File)
      {
          using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
         {
            File.CopyTo(stream);
            entity.File = stream.ToArray();

        }

        _context.Movie.Add(entity);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return Ok();
    }
```

---

```
 @model IEnumerable<FileUploads.Models.Movie>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index1";
  }

 <h1>Index1</h1>
  <table>

    <tr>

      @foreach (var item in Model)
       {

          <td>

            @{ 


                var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(item.File);
                var imgsrc = string.Format("data:image/jpeg;base64,{0}",  base64);
            }

            <img src='@imgsrc' style="max-height:100px;max-width:100px"/>
            }


</td>

        }

    </tr>

</table>
_________
```

---

This is how my have post method, get method and view page  looks.

Please help me. How do I get the original JPEG  format image? It would be helpful if you can show me the the View Page also.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what the actual problem is. The code you have should work.

However, this is not the correct approach, regardless, so instead of wasting time trying to debug it, you should simply do it right instead.

The problem with using data URIs is two-fold:

1. You're basically embedding the image(s) in the HTML response, which means that it's going to be very large and potentially take a long time to download. The web browser cannot begin to render the page until it has received the full HTML document, so the larger that document is, the longer before first meaningful paint (i.e. you'll be staring at a blank screen). One image may not be too bad, but the problem becomes exponentially worse the more you add in this way. Your HTML document could end up being megabytes in size, and especially with mobile data a premium that's not good.
2. Base64 is an inefficient encoding. As the name implies, every byte is represented by a combination of 64 ASCII characters. Since a byte can encode 256 numbers, it takes  up to 4 characters (which are 1-2 bytes each) to represent each individual byte in the image. In case it's not clear, that means you image size is going to *balloon*. A fairly run of the mill 50-60KB JPEG could cost as much as 240KB Base64 encoded, which only serves to exasperate, the page size issue described first.

Long and short, the correct way to do this to serve the image via an action. For example:

```
[HttpGet("movie-image/{movieId}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> MovieImage(int movieId)
{
    var movieImage = _context.Movie.Where(x => x.Id == movieId).Select(a => a.File).SingleOrDefault();
    if (movieImage == null)
        return NotFound();

    return File(movieImage, "image/jpeg");
}
```

Then, in your view:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("MovieImage", new { movieId = item.Id })" />
```

You might also consider adding some cache headers so that the browser will cache the image, and load it from cache instead of hitting the server each time its shown in the future:

```
Response.Headers.Add(HeaderNames.CacheControl, $"max-age={TimeSpan.FromDays(365).TotalSeconds}");
return File(movieImage, "image/jpeg");
```

And finally, since the URL that will be cached is tied to the movie id and not the physical image, you might consider employing Etags, just in case you need to update the image. This is a bit more advanced, and not strictly necessary. Worst case scenario, the old image might be loaded from cache, if the user has already downloaded it previously.

Regardless, to generate an Etag, you need to generate a hash of the image bytes:

```
string checksum;
using (var sha256 = SHA256.Create())
{
    checksum = Convert.ToBase64String(sha256.ComputeHash(movieImage));
}

if (Request.Headers.TryGetValue(HeaderNames.IfNoneMatch, out var etag && checksum == etag)
    return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.NotModified);

Response.Headers.Add(HeaderNames.CacheControl, $"max-age={TimeSpan.FromDays(365).TotalSeconds}");
Response.Headers.Add(HeaderNames.Etag, checksum);
return File(movieImage, "image/jpeg");
```

Comment: I have one more doubt what if my database contains more than 1 image and i want a list of image to be displayed?

Comment: You still return just one image per the action. There's no way to return multiple images in one response. The action just makes it like it was a static image. You're just calling the URL to the action instead of the path to a physical file being served by your web server directly.